# SOLR highlighting other words also, other than search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I have integrated the SOLR with Rails application by using the `Sunspot` gem. And I found that sometimes the SOLR highlighting the other words. If I search `capital` its highlighting `capital borrowed` , `capital byputting` words. I don't know why its highlighting the `borrowed or byputting` words.

My solrconfig.xml contains the following configutration

```
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
<highlighting>
  <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
  <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
  <fragmenter name="gap" 
              default="true"
              class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
    </lst>
  </fragmenter>

  <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
       (for sentence extraction) 
    -->
  <fragmenter name="regex" 
              class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
      <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
      <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
      <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
      <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
      <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
    </lst>
  </fragmenter>

  <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
  <formatter name="html" 
             default="true"
             class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
      <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
    </lst>
  </formatter>

  <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
  <encoder name="html" 
           class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

  <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
  <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                   class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

  <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
  <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                   class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

  <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
  <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                   default="true"
                   class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

  <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
  <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                    default="true"
                    class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
    <!-- 
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
    </lst>
    -->
  </fragmentsBuilder>

  <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
  <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                    class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
           <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
           <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
           <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
           <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
           <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
      <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
    </lst>
  </fragmentsBuilder>

  <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                   default="true"
                   class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
      <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
    </lst>
  </boundaryScanner>

  <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                   class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
      <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
      <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
      <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
      <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
      <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
    </lst>
  </boundaryScanner>
</highlighting>
```

I have a content in html form and I am doing the highlighting on that content. Is anyone know the solution, please help me to figure the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the use of solr synonyms. You probably have a file called synonyms.txt in your conf folder. For more info: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory